# How do I get the toast message to pop up when the function is called

Tags: reactjs

When I call or click the function, the message does not open. It doesn't allow me to use hooks on the page either. So I didn't know what to do. If I could use hook I could add state. When I checked it with Console.log, I saw that the data came to the page.

```
export const toastMessage = (
  title,
  text,
  type
) => {
  const toastContent = (
    <div>
        <div
          className={cx(
            styles.toast,
            type === "success"
              ? styles.success
              : type === "warning"
              ? styles.warning
              : styles.danger,
          )}
        >
          <div className={styles.content}>
            <div className={styles.desc}>
              {title && <span>{title}</span>}
              {text && <p>{text}</p>}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I call it like this on the another page:

```
function handleClick() {
    toastMessage("title", "content", "success");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `return` statement

```
function handleClick() {
    return toastMessage("title", "content", "success");
  }
```

Comment: it didn't work @BouncyBits